# Gevent,http/cgi non blocking server

Tags: python, cgi, gevent, concurrent-programming

I have this methods:

```
class dJobs():
    def server(self):
        address = ('127.0.0.1', dConfig.cgiport)
        handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
        handler.cgi_directories = ['/cgi-bin']
        self.logger.info("starting http server on port %s" %str(port))
        httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(address, handler)
        httpd.serve_forever()

    def job(self):
        self.runNumber = 0
        while True:
            self.logger.info("Counting: %s" %str(self.runNumber))
            self.runNumber+=1
            time.sleep(1)
```

I want run job while waiting for http and cgi requests, handle requests and then continue job method.
Is it possibile to do this using gevent (and how), or i need to use threading ?

i.e. I want to run both method concurrently without creating threads.

Comment: Could you fix your indentation?

Comment: Can you run it as is? When I try, I get `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. You probably want to indent the methods.

Comment: right,sure, i thought you was speaking about tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution seems to work for me:

- import monkey:

  ```
  from gevent import monkey
  monkey.patch_all(thread=False)
  ```
- add and run this method:

  ```
  def run(self):
     jobs = [gevent.spawn(self.server),gevent.spawn(self.job)]
     gevent.joinall(jobs)
  ```

Please try it out in your program.

Answer (score 0):

If your job is CPU-bound, you must not use Python threads because of [GIL](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/NewGIL.pdf). Alternative is [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Also you could use [uWSGI](https://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/)--it can do [CGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/CGI.html?highlight=cgi#running-cgi-scripts-on-uwsgi) and run [jobs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Mules.html#uwsgi-mules). Look at the WSGI which is the main feature of uWSGI, you may want to use that instead of CGI.

Comment: Both solutions are not feasible cause my app will be a single process daemon (double forked). Thanks anyway, you made me know a very useful tools (uWSGI).

Comment: @salvo Then provide more info on what your limitations are and why you think you have them.